# Can I use Luxon to combine a DateTime with a time string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, luxon

I've got a `TimePicker` component that returns a 24-hour time in this format: `09:00` for 9AM or `12:00` for 12PM or `20:00` for 8PM. Something in my code requires a `Date` (JSDate) so I want to just take the current date/time `DateTime.now()` but apply the hours and minutes from the `TimePicker` component which has an `onClick` event. I can handle that event like so:

```js
// TimePickerValue can either be a string or JSDate
// but the TimePicker is always returning a string
const handleTimeChange = (time:TimePickerValue) => {
  // this outputs a time in 24-hour format
  console.log("handleTimeChange: ", time) 
    
  // I want to set the state of the parent component
  // this needs to be in JSDate format so this doesn't work
  // setSomeValue(time)

  // Because I don't care about date, I can just use "now()" and convert
  // it to a JSDate but I want the hours and minutes of the value I'm setting
  // to be the time in the string being sent to this function.
  setSomeValue(DateTime.now().toJSDate())
}
```

Can Luxon parse something like "13:00" or apply it an existing `DateTime` so it writes over its existing `hours` and `minutes`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can Luxon parse something like "13:00"

Yes, [you can just use the `fromISO` method to parse a time string](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/parsing.html).

```
const parsed = DateTime.fromISO('20:00');
console.log(parsed.toString());  // 2021-04-07T20:00:00.000+10:00
```

> Can Luxon apply it to an existing DateTime so it writes over its existing hours and minutes?

This could be a bit harder, I don't know if there's a "built-in" way in Luxon to do that. But, if you parse the time string using `fromISO`, it will set the date part to "today", so you could use `diff` to work out the "time of day" (as a `Duration`) and then use that to set the time of day on your other date:

```
const parsed = DateTime.fromISO(time);
const today = DateTime.now().startOf('day');
const timeOfDay = parsed.diff(today);

const dateToModify = DateTime.fromJSDate(otherDate);
const result = dateToModify.startOf('day').plus(timeOfDay);
```

Alternatively, if you have the "parts" of the time, you can use [Luxon's `set` method](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-set) to overwrite those individual parts:

```
const dateToModify = DateTime.fromJSDate(otherDate);

// Not sure what's in the 'TimePickerValue' object but if you had hours and minutes:
const result = dateToModify.set({
    hour: time.hours,
    minute: time.minutes,
});
```

Comment: It's hour and minute instead of hours and minutes in the above .set example
REF https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-set

Comment: Thanks for the pickup @JBB - I've fixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I am currently working with Strapi and used its Datepicker component. This component returns JSDate.

[image]

```
 const ourTime = "17:34"
 // Parse time to object
 const { minute, hour } = DateTime.fromFormat(ourTime, 'hh:mm').toObject()

 const dt = DateTime.fromJSDate(dateFromComponent, { zone: 'gmt' })
 const inLocal = dt.toLocal().setZone('yourZone')
 console.log(inLocal, 'Our current date')
```

**What we have for now in *console.log*:**
[image]

```
 const addedHoursAndMinutes = inLocal.set({ hour: hour, minute: minute })
 console.log(
     inLocal.set({ hour: hour, minute: minute }),  // Here is magic happens
     'Our current date with overwritten hours and mins'
 )
```

**And we get what we need:**
[image]

---

Answer in short:

**You can use `.set({ hour: 17, minute: 34 })` on luxon's DateTime object.**

*P.S.* Works not only for hours and minutes. `.set({years: 2001,months: 5,days: 5,hours: 0,minutes: 0,seconds: 0,milliseconds: 0})` Pay no attention to [s] at the end of the words (hour/hours, day/days, etc - both variants are working)